# In-app purchase without login/registration system

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, storekit

I need to integrate in-app purchase to an app. It's an app with **static content**. It can help  user prepare for the fishing license exam. So users can go through all the questions for free, but they can try some sample exams only when they are premium. The app is totally offline and **without login/registration system**.

Since the users will probably use the app just before passing the exam and they need probably between 1 and 3 months to prepare, it does not make sense to offer an auto-renewable subscription. So my idea is to offer three option:

- Unlock premium feature for 1 month. (non auto-renewable subscription
  ??)
- Unlock premium feature for 3 months. (non auto-renewable
  subscription ??)
- Get a lifetime access. ( non-consumable in-app ??)

So my question is:

Assuming that the first two options will be done via non auto-renewable subscription (let me know if you have another idea). Will it be a problem that my app does not have any registration or login system? Maybe somehow identify the user (if it's really needed? to use the app in the different device with the same AppleID) by just his AppleID (I know that I don't have access to this but maybe StoreKit have this possibility) using StoreKit. And do you see any flaw or technical issue that I can face in my proposed in-app purchase strategy

Comment: Since they are non-renewing/non-consumable IAPs you can use the storekit receipt data; you can see when a subscription was purchased and compare to the current date. You probably want to fetch the current date from an internet server since the user could change their device date. All you need is a "restore purchase" button for users to access their purchase on another device

Comment: @Paulw11 and how the "restore purchase" will work in the other device since I don't have a registration/login system in the app ?

Comment: You ask StoreKit to restore the purchases. Apple knows what the user has purchased. And will present those purchases to you again. For the non-consumable, that is straightforward. For the subscription you will need to look at the receipt and find the original purchase dates and decide if the subscription is still active. You then activate the features if required. No need for a login system

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you that's really reassuring. Can you please point me to a some technical resources that cover my use case ?